Intuition behind the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {n-1}{n!}=1$?
I've been fiddling around with some sums, and got this result:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {n-1}{n!}=1$$
I've managed to prove this using the Taylor series of e^x, but I'm looking for some Intuition/logic that isn't just some algebraic maneuvering.
Any contribution welcome!

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

Look at $(e^x)' - e^x$ at point $x=1$

This is just a telescoping sum:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n-1}{n!} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{(n-1)!} - \frac{1}{n!}\right) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} = \frac{1}{0!} = 1.$$
